# Why is main() the only method executing?

Tags: java, testing, methods, jframe, program-entry-point

Whenever I run my program (Which only consists of a JFrame in main and another public void method) it only runs the main method. I know this is the case because when I test System.out.println("Test"); in the second method it doesn't execute but if I do the same line of code in main in will execute as expected

```
package com.route.route;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
public class Window extends JFrame {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;



public void gfsdagfds(){
    System.out.println("Hello");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setTitle("route UNREALEASED 0.01");
    frame.setIconImage(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}
```

}

Comment: And what was your expectation, exactly? Just execute all methods it stumbles upon?

Comment: ...so why would it randomly execute methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're calling any other methods. main() is just the entry point into the application. You'll need to call the method:

```
main(String[] args){
...
gfsdagfds()
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never call your `gfsdagfds()` method within `main()`. Methods will only execute if called from `main()`, as it is the only method called from the JVM. If you put a call to `gfsdagfds()` inside `main()` you will see "hello" in `System.out`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't calling the second method, so of course it isn't being executed.

You won't be able to call the second method (non-static) from `main` (which is static). You can fix that by using a `Window` as your object instead of `JFrame`, and then you can call `frame.gfsdagfds()`.